# Is it possible to record a video as avi or mp4?

Tags: motorola-milestone, video-recording

I've recently bought a Motorola Milestone 2 (Froyo) and I see that when I record a video it produces a .3gp file.
Is there a way to have it produce an avi or mp4 instead? Would I have to root the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root won't be necessary, [the Android API allows Apps to set the output file format to .mp4](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.html#MPEG_4). So you just need to find an App that makes use of it.

**But,** as with most video file extensions, `.avi` and [`.mp4`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mp4) are just [container formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_format_%28digital%29). Therefore the actually used video codec, that is responsible for the quality of the video, isn't changed by changing the container format. The Android API itself recommends to use `.3gp` as container format for better compatibility.

> Using an MPEG-4 container format may confuse some desktop players.

<sup>[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setOutputFormat%28int%29)</sup>

I'm not aware of an Android video recording app that actually saves the video with [H.264/AVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) compression. I think that this is because of the royalty fee one has to pay to use the codec.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to save as .AVI? My phone (Motorola Razr) records in .MP4 and I'd like to edit it w/ windows movie maker, which doesn't recognize .MP4